# Does Photo Mechanic import faster than Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, photo-mechanic

I've recently found myself being encumbered by LRs slow rendering so I want to use Photo Mechanic. But I wonder if Photo Mechanic ingests faster than LR imports?

It seems to me that just copying files would be just as fast? I'm assuming that "render previews" is set to minimal and "smart previews" is off.

Comment: Yes it is much faster. Many people use it for the first round of culling then move to Lightroom for the rest of their work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you install the trial of Photomechanic and give it a try, that is the only way you will ever really know. It is my experience that Photomechanic will ingest your pictures MUCH faster than Lightroom, but it does not give you all of the editing capabilities that Lightroom does. They are very different tools.

Comment: I did just that and came up with about 3 minutes faster (12.5 to 9 minutes) for 11GB worth of files off of a class 10 SD card.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With Lightroom, you can choose what quality level you want the preview images to be, and also what level of quality you want the full sized image to be while you are working on it, and whether you want each image "ingested" (as you put it) when you import the image or not until you open the image. So there can be a great variation within Lightroom based on the settings you select.

Comment: I should have added, I'm assuming that "render previews" is set to minimal and "smart previews" is off.